# Error not present in onExit method when link token flow fails

Tags: plaid

I'm looking to do some error handling when our users fail to complete the link token flow but I'm not seeing the error when I get into the `onExit` method ([in the docs here](https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/#onexit)). As a result, I can't tell when a user has just closed the link flow or actually run into an issue.

I opened the link flow, waited 30 minutes, and then attempted to complete the process.

I expected an error to occur and for this error to be accessible within the `onExit` method.

An error did occur (400 bad request that was visible in the browser's dev tools) but this error was not accessible within the `onExit` method for my use.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this and what I found was in the scenario you described, Link spontaneously closes during the flow. This does not result in an `onExit` callback, since `onExit` is only triggered when the *user* closes Link.

This is probably suboptimal behavior, but it's also the case that Link failing in that way (with the Link token expiring) is rare. A more typical situation in which you'd see an error in `onExit` is something like this:

- User attempts to log into their bank account but enters the wrong password
- User eventually gives up and closes Link

In that situation, `onExit` would have an error object indicating an invalid credentials error.

Comment: I just retested to confirm and I do appear to end up in the `onExit` callback. I'm seeing the redirect behaviour I've detailed in the callback and to be double-sure added a console log that was called.

I'm specifically trying to cover this as it's mentioned as an error flow in the Plaid docs ([see here](https://plaid.com/docs/link/handle-invalid-link-token/)), but I'm okay to just use the normal `onExit` behaviour if the error isn't coming through.

I'm also not seeing a way to test the "wrong password" flow through the Plaid sandbox - do you know if this is detailed anywhere in the docs?

Comment: @CurtisBateson it should be testable via triggering the wrong password error "organically" -- enter an incorrect password for the sandbox user, then close Link.

Comment: Our sandbox doesn't require a password to connect. I can click the "Simulate error" option but that doesn't result in an INVALID_LINK_TOKEN error when I close the link. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @CurtisBateson The flow you're describing is what shows up for institutions that use OAuth. Try a non-OAuth institution (generally those are regional banks, not ones in the top 10 -- off the top of my head, Citizens Bank and Regions Bank are two examples).